# jQuery Disable textarea with certain content

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of `textarea`s which by default should be active, but when containing a certain text it should be disabled.

HTML

```
<textarea id="my_ta_1">Example 1</textarea>
<textarea id="my_ta_2">Example 2</textarea>
<textarea id="my_ta_3">Example 3</textarea>
```

jQuery (Trying to disable the `textarea` with `Example 2` inside.)

```
if (!$('[id*="my_ta_"]').val(Example 2))
 {$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");}
```

Is it possible?

And am i anywhere near ? =)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLEtx/)

I am using following jQuery to change to text of `textarea` #my_ta_2

```
$('select').change( function()
 {var text1 = $('select option:selected').val();
  $('#my_ta_2').html(text1);
 }
);
```

Is it possible to make it active again when that happens?

Comment: Is it possible to make it re-enable the textarea if the text changes

Comment: If it's disabled then you can't change the text.

Comment: With above code i can, but it stays disabled

Comment: Check the updated answer for re-enabling the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (it'll disable the `textarea` when you type `Example 2` in any `textarea`  which has an `id` starting with `my_ta_`)

```
$('[id^="my_ta_"]').on('keyup', function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if(txt.match(/Example 2/)){
        $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
    }
});
```

It'll even match the `example 2` from `Some text Example 1 but example 2`.

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLEtx/5/)

**Update :** To initially check for the text `example 2` and make it `disabled` there are other (up voted) answers, pick one that you like but I wrote the code to check `textarea` when user writes in the `textarea` and if it finds `example 2(in any case/any where)` then the `textarea` will be disabled.

**Update :**
To re-enable the `disabled textarea` using a `select` value

```
$('[id^="my_ta_"]').on('keyup change', function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if(txt.match(/Example 2/i)){
        $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
    }
    else $(this).prop('disabled', 0);
});

// works on (re-enables) my_ta_2
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var text1 = $(this).val();
    $('#my_ta_2').val(text1).trigger('change');
});
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLEtx/6/)

**Update :** Maybe you may try this too (initially check and disable and re-enable on change again)

```
$('textarea[id^="my_ta_"]').prop('disabled', function(){
    return $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase()) == 'example 2'
})
.on('change', function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if(txt.match(/example 2/i)){
        $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
    }
    else $(this).prop('disabled', 0);
});

// works on (re-enables) my_ta_2
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var text1 = $(this).val();
    $('#my_ta_2').val(text1).trigger('change');
});
```

[**Example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLEtx/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `filter()` and filter out whatever value you'd like :

```
$('textarea[id^="my_ta_"]').filter(function() {
    return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('example 2') != -1;
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

an example disabling any textarea containing the string 'example 2' case-insensitive.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vFYKK/)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a getter method on a jQuery wrapper set, it will return the value of the first element of the set... it will ignore the rest of the elements in the set...

Also you where setting the value of the textarea's instead of getting them to compare...

You need to use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue) setter that takes a function as a parameter

```
$('textarea[id*="my_ta_"]').prop('disabled', function(){
    return $.trim(this.value) == 'Example 2'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/65psX/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
  if($(this).text() !== "Example 2"){
     $(this).attr("disabled","disabled")
  }
});
```

Try the above. If you have additional tetareas that you don't want to be affected just wrap the specified ones in a parent and find them relative to their parent

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, here's one way to do it:

```
var text_to_match = "Example 2";

$('[id*="my_ta_"]').each(function(){
    var cur_value = $(this).val();
    if(cur_value === text_to_match){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shane3/ckWUJ/)